# How to get polygons to display 'room' or 'equipment' and not nest together?

Tags: tableau

I have a dataset where I have Rooms and inside the Rooms are pieces of equipment. The way the data is scrubbed is that equipment has an equipment name and room number and the room just has a room number. When I add the polygons over to the equipment and add my risk factor calculation to display a heat map, the equipment polygon displays the room risk factor instead of the equipment risk factor. Unfortunately, the equipment must retain its room number. How can I point my data sources to indicate that if an equipment name is present then display the equipment, else display the room.

Here is some info ands pictures:

[image] [image]

Here we have three polygons. The two smaller polygons are part of the larger room and thus have the same room number. The room has a yellow risk factor, however the pieces of equipment have a green risk factor. The calculation for determining this is accurate, however it is displaying the room risk over the equipment risk.

Here is how the data is structured:

`Master Data` connection with `Shape coords`

The connection between them is by `Room`, however, there is an `Equipment` connection as well but it removes the `Room` when used, however, the risk display is correct.

[image]

The only two similar columns between the `Master Data` and `Shape coords` are `Room` and `Equipment`. Hoping someone can help out - TIA!

Comment: Could you add a screen of how a tbw workbook is organized? Or give a tbwx file..